# Cut array after key in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to cut array after key in Ruby, for example:

```
=> ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"] # Cut after "Baz"
=> ["Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"] # result
```

It's possible to do? How can I do that?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just specify the range from index to -1(last element):

```
arr = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]
arr[arr.index("Baz")..-1] # =>  ["Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]
```

Comment: More changes needed to handle situation if one tried to cut around non-existing element, say - `Bazzzzzzzzzz` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]

arr.select { |s| s=='Baz'..nil ? 'Baz' : nil }
  #=> ["Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]
```

Look odd? What's going on here?

Comment: [Link to manual](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#range) to prevent other guys from being brain f*ed too much. You are dreadful man, Cary:)

Comment: Good one! @RustamA.Gasanov

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
a = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]

a.drop_while {|e| e != "Baz"}
#=> ["Baz", "ooF", "raB", "zaB"]

a.drop_while {|e| e != "Bazzzzzzz"}
#=> []
```